# Why does axios always convert https into http when making request?

Tags: http, https, vuejs2, axios, laravel-5.8

I am working with Laravel 5.8 and out-of-the-box pre-configured Vue.js.

For making a GET/POST/PUT/DELETE request within Vue.js components, I am using AXIOS as following:

```
import axios from 'axios'

const obj = axios.create({
  baseURL: '/controller-name/action-function-name'
})

export default {
  all (params) {
    return obj.get('/', params)
  },
  find (id) {
    return obj.get(`/${id}`)
  },
  store (data) {
    return obj.post(``, data)
  },
  update (id, data) {
    return obj.put(`/${id}`, data)
  },
  delete (id) {
    return obj.delete(`/${id}`)
  }
}
```

Everything works fine in my local environment with a `HTTP` virtual host e.g. `http://my-website.com`. Until I deployed my application on a real hosting server with `HTTPS` url e.g. `https://my-website.com`, my app does not work any more and I get the following error.

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://my-website.com/path#/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://my-website.com/path/controller-name/action-function-name'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

I do understand that because my application is running on `HTTPS` domain but the request that `AXIOS` makes is via `HTTP`. That's why it does not work.

My question is why does AXIOS covert `HTTPS` into `HTTP` url when making a request?

I did try the following with hard code url.

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  all (params) {
    return obj.get('https://my-website.com/controller-name/action-function-name/', params)
  },
  find (id) {
    return obj.get(`https://my-website.com/controller-name/action-function-name/${id}`)
  },
  store (data) {
    return obj.post(`https://my-website.com/controller-name/action-function-name`, data)
  },
  update (id, data) {
    return obj.put(`https://my-website.com/controller-name/action-function-name/${id}`, data)
  },
  delete (id) {
    return obj.delete(`https://my-website.com/controller-name/action-function-name/${id}`)
  }
}
```

As you can see, all hard code url is prefixed with `https`. Every time I click on a menu link, `AXIOS` always overrides my `https` hard code url with `http` url. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 2):

If actually it works for someone, the problem is in the back. The URL to receive must not have '/' at the end, because if it has caused a redirection to http

*Example*:

**Before**:

```
@app.route('/api/color/primary/',methods = ['GET'])
```

**After**:

```
@app.route('/api/color/primary',methods = ['GET'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you do the following:

```
baseURL: 'https://yourdomain.com/',
url: '/controller-name/action-function-name',
```

Comment: Your answer did help a little bit, it now applies the configured baseURL, url must be set as well when creating an instance object of axios, but it does not use the configured url to go the action function name of the controller. Thanks for trying to help!

Comment: I have found the solution. Actually, url is not required to be set and baseURL is not required to be full domain name. My first block of code snippet is correct. The problem was that my controller is a normal web controller that response JSON data which can be access via web browser. It needs to be a Restful API to handle request from AXIOS. My case is about Vue.js with AXIOS within Laravel 5.8.